# jquery fancybox - append to current instance of fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-3

currently this is how I'm doing right now

```
$('.fancybox-inner').append(html);
```

suppose if there are two instances of fancybox opened, above code will append html to both instances of fancybox but I want to append it to current instance.

How can I achieve this ?

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: give different `id` or `class` to various elements and then use `$('#id1 .fancybox-inner')` to select the particular box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each instance contains variable `$refs` that is collection of references to DOM objects. So, you can change your snippet to:

```
$.fancybox.getInstance().$refs.inner.append(html);
```

btw, if you are executing this code from within callback, then you already have a reference to the instance (first argument)